# Incomplete image coverage of Area of Interest (AOI) in Earth Engine using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-earth-engine, sentinel2, geemap

> I am working on analyzing satellite imagery in Earth Engine for an
> Area of Interest (AOI) specified by a shapefile polygon using python 3
> on a jupyter notebook. However, the satellite images retrieved using
> the COPERNICUS/S2 image collection only partially cover the AOI. This
> is because the images are split into a fixed grid, and some tiles
> never get completely covered by a single image. As shown below;

[image: The retrieve image does not cover the aoi]

> To solve this issue, I want to create an algorithm that first checks
> whether the retrieved images cover the AOI completely or not. If they
> don't, I want to mosaic all intersecting images to get the full AOI
> extent while retaining the band properties for analysis.
> But as you can observe in the snippet below, it is not working as desired

[image: The image was only found in the area circled with RED]

Here's the code I've tried so far:

> ## initiazing map
>
> ```
> Map = geemap.Map()
>
> # Map.add_basemap('SATELLITE')
> Map.add_basemap('ROADMAP')
>
>
> shapefile_path = r"..\data\data_ghana\upper denkyira west\upper denkyira west.shp"
> aoi = geemap.shp_to_ee(shapefile_path)
> Map.addLayer(aoi,{},'AOI')
>
>
> s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED") \
>     .filterBounds(aoi) \
>     .filterDate("2019-01-01","2019-12-31")\
>     .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
>
> # Check whether the retrieved images cover the AOI completely
> if s2.geometry().contains(aoi):
>     # Images cover the AOI completely, proceed with analysis
>     s2_aoi = s2.first().clip(aoi)
>     print("AOI is completely within the Tile")
> else:
>     # Images do not cover the AOI completely, mosaic intersecting images
>     s2_aoi = s2.mosaic().clip(aoi)
>     print("AOI not covered")
>
> Map.addLayer(s2_aoi,{},"s2")
> ```

**Can anyone suggest an algorithm that can mosaic all intersecting images to cover the full AOI extent while retaining the band properties for analysis?**